# Using sanitize-html for node, how to remove specific tags that are included by default

Tags: html, node.js

Using [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) I would like to remove SPAN tags from HTML, but it seems there is no remove-tags option? As SPAN tags are included by default, it seems the only option is to recreate the list of preserved tags in totality (and not include SPAN) in that list?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you read about filters? https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html#user-content-filters

Answer (score 0):

In fact one can simply set `allowedTags` to the initial set, without the tags we don't want.

So, using lodash for example, this works:

```
allowedTags: _.difference(sanitizeHtml.defaults.allowedTags, ['span'])
```

`sanitizeHtml.defaults.allowedTags` is the initial list of allowed tags; the difference creates a new list without 'span' in it; then we reset the list of allowed tags to the new list.

(This is much better than retyping the whole list, because it makes obvious what tag was removed, and it avoids errors).